# How do you get nested key value of a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I'd like to iterate over a hash ref and get keys if they exist, but the keys that I want are at the second level of the hash ref. I want to be able to get to this key for all first level keys of the hash ref that have it

Example:

```
    my $total = 0;
    foreach my $student (keys $students) {
        if ( exists $student->{???}->{points} ) {
            $total += $student->{points};
        }
    }
    return $total;
```

The problem I've run into is that I want to "not care" what the value of `$student->{???}` is, just want to get to the `{points}` for it

Comment: why would you want to close the question, this isn't debugging, but rather about understanding looping over hashes in perl.

Comment: What's wrong with just iterating over the second level hash?

Comment: why not:  `if ( exists $students->{$student}->{points} ) {`?

Comment: Yeah, just tried that, but getting the following eror: type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref

Comment: `foreach my $student (keys %{$students}){`

Comment: because keys `%$students` if your your have a hashref instead of hash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up your `$students` variable with your `$student` variable:

```
    if ( exists $student->{???}->{points} ) {
                ^^^^^^^^
                Should be $students
```

However, if you don't care about the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) of your first level HoH, then simply don't iterate on them.

Just iterate on the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(sum);

my $students = {
    bob => { points => 17 },
    amy => { points => 12 },
    foo => { info   => 'none' },
    bar => { points => 13 },
};

my $total = sum map { $_->{points} // 0 } values %$students;

print "$total is the answer\n";
```

Outputs:

```
42 is the answer
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up doing foreach my $student (keys %$students) { if ( exists $students->{$student}->{points} ) {...} }, as the sum map() is beyond me right now. will try and refactor to that as it is a one liner. Thanks also for pointing out my mistake about using $student, now I understand how to go through loops with hashes